# Rails not Saving the Right Info to the DB Using Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code:

```
<%= f.select(:title, options_for_select([['Pick a reason',0],['Title 1', 1], ['Title 2', 2]),:class=>"input-xlarge", :type=>"text")%>
```

When selecting it, the number gets saved to the DB, not the text. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The number with the string is the value of the select. Just use an array of strings as options: `['Pick a reason', 'Title 1', 'Title 2']`

Comment: well i need the number. because depending on the number a text box is being display (using jquery).

Comment: I need the `option value` to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you want is:

```
<%= f.select(:title, options_for_select([['Pick a reason', nil,{:<some_html_tag> => 0}],['Title 1', 'Title 1',{:<some_html_tag> => 1}], ['Title 2','Title 2', {:<some_html_tag> => 2}]),:class=>"input-xlarge", :type=>"text")%>
```

the second part of the array specifies the value, which is what is saved to the db, but the third part allows any arbitrary html attributes.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Comment: so in this case if i select `Title 2` , will the same be saved to the db?

Comment: actually no, right now there are two values generated in the html `value="Pick a reason" value="0"`. any clues?

Comment: I don't think you should use value as the tag to use, value should be exactly what you want to save to the db, class or id would be work better?